# Electron - share the same IndexedDB across multiple windows of the same app

Tags: session, window, electron, indexeddb

I'd like to share the same "instance" of IndexedDB across multiple windows of the same app. Given `win1` and `win2`, I'd like to be able to store some `data` in `win1` IndexedDB, and then get the same `data` in `win2`.

Currently in dev tools I have checked that two different IndexedDB are being served to each window. As a consequence, `data` of `win1` is not available to `win2`, and viceversa.

In Electron's documentation for [BrowserWindow](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md) I've noticed that you can set the value `partition`, which should make the same [session](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/session) available to all windows.

In this way I should be able to share the same instance of IndexedDB, but I'm unable to get it working.

I've set the following options for both windows:

```
const options = {
  webPreferences: {
    partition: 'persist:myapp'
  }
};
```

However, they still get two different IndexedDBs.

Comment: Dealing with the same requirement. Have you tried creating a session using `Session.fromPartition()` first, and passing it directly to `webPreferences`?

Comment: Mmmm no, that might be a good idea. I ended up building a system to communicate data between windows, and I have a DB window that handles all DB-related tasks

Comment: I’m curious, is it better to have a window for DB tasks rather than do them in `main`? Sorry if it’s obvious

Comment: @Tony, probably it depends on the use case. In mine, I'm already using main for several tasks, and I wanted to avoid pushing also DB related activities. On top of that I wanted to use indexeddb without having to implement a DB of some sort on main